# Finding tags within comment tags - Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape tables from a website using BeautifulSoup/Python. For some reason or another, one of the tables appears to live inside comment tags.  I can get the entirety of the text inside the comment tags, but I can't figure out how to run find_all commands on that text to be able to find the table within it.

Is there some way to tell it that the text found inside the comment tag is, in fact, more HTML?

hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201701260BOS.html

I'm trying to get the 2 tables under the Advanced Stats Report section

Comment: No, because anything inside a comment is not a HTML structure. It's a comment. *Probably* some Javascript code is involved loading data into the page after loading (via AJAX, not from a comment), but without a proper example we can't really help.

Comment: http://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201701260BOS.html

I'm trying to get the 2 tables under the Advanced Stats Report section

Comment: post the url and the output you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

# use table text find comment text
table_text = soup.find(text=re.compile('table class="adv sortable stats_table"')) 

# use bs4 to parse the text
table_soup = BeautifulSoup(table_text, 'lxml')
# find_all ....
table_soup.find_all('tr')
```